# change of variable, how to determine the bounds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-basis

[image]
so the answer I have is something like

$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-v}^{0}...dudv$, I'm ok with the jacobin matrix, but I just don't know how to get the bounds of u, v which are 0 to 2 and -v to 0

[image]

It looks like two regions that can be the new region for uv variables, which one should I use?

Comment: Graph the triangle $T.$ with the given (x,y) vertices.  What are the equations of the 3 lines connecting the vertices ? Substitute $x$ and $y$ with the given transformation to get the corresponding lines (and the vertices) in the $u,v$ plane.

Comment: @VivekKaushik I have added equations to the graph, but I still don't get how to determine u and v, could you plz show me in more details?

Comment: I put a more detailed response as an answer. Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have equations $y=x$ and $y=-x+2$ and $y=0,$ which you found to be the equations of the three lines.

Now look at the first equation $y=x.$ This is equivalent to $y-x=0.$ Observe that $u=y-x$ by the given transformation. This implies the line $y-x=0$ transforms to $u=0.$

Look at the second equation $y=-x+2.$ This implies $y+x=2.$ From your given transformation $v=y+x,$ so $y+x=2$ transforms to $v=2.$

Look at the third equation $y=0.$ Observe that $y=\frac{u+v}{2}$ by your given transformation. This means $y=0$ transforms to $\frac{u+v}{2}=0$ or $u+v=0$ multiplying both sides by $2.$

Thus the new triangle in the $u-v$ plane is bounded by equations $u+v=0$ , $v=2$ and $u=0.$ Graph this. Does this help ?

Comment: I added a new graph to the original question, it looks like there are two regions can both to be the new boundaries, which one should I use?

Comment: The first region (the one you labeled $1$) . If you want to see why that is, find the equations of the 3 lines in the second region. You will see that you are missing $v=2,$ which, if you look at my answer, was the result of transforming $y+x=2.$